# C# void method doesnt change variable outside of the method

Tags: c#

i tryed to do that:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        Methode(a, b);
        c = a + b;
        Textbox.Text = c.ToString();
    }
    private void Methode(int _a, int _b)
    {
        _a += 1;
        _b += 2;

    }
}
```

}

First it worked fine and the variables a and b got changed and the summary was 3 in the textbox, but after a while of debugging it stopped working and i did not change any code. Now the text is 0 in the textbox. Can somebody help me? It stopped to change the variables outside of the method without making any changes. Im using visual studio 2019

Comment: There's no way this could ever have worked, `int` is a value type and so unless you explicitly use the `ref` keyword, it won't change.

Comment: You should read about value types vs reference types, then about the `ref` and `out` keywords. Those are well-documented topics that you can easily find in learn.microsoft.com

Comment: Check about Passing parameters (arguments) into method at MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Comment: my guess is that this assignment is exactly build to teach you the difference between a "value" and a "reference" type. Probably you have it already on your lecture slides. If not, the research it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_a` and `_b` are passed by value. Changing them in the scope of the method won't change the values of `a` and `b` passed to them.
One option is to explicitly pass them by reference by using `ref`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    Methode(ref a, ref b);
    c = a + b;
    Textbox.Text = c.ToString();
}

private void Methode(ref int _a, ref int _b)
{
    _a += 1;
    _b += 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it works. I got it work with the ref keyword